# QSqlTableModel.insertRecord() is very slow

Tags: qt, insert, performance, pyqt, record

I am using PyQt to insert records into a MySQL database. the code basically looks like

```
self.table = QSqlTableModel()
self.table.setTable('mytable')
while True:
  rec = self.table.record()
  values = getValueDictionary()
  for k,v in values.items():
    rec.setValue(k,QVariant(v))
  self.table.insertRecord(-1,rec)
```

The table currently has ~ 50,000 rows in it.
I have timed each line and found that the insertRecord function is taking ~5 seconds to execute, which is unacceptably slow. Everything else is fast.

For comparison, I also made a version of the code that uses

```
QSqlQuery.prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (f1,f2,...) VALUES (:f1, :f2,...)")
query.bindValue(":f1",blah)
query.exec_()
```

In this case, the whole thing takes only ~ 20 milliseconds, so the delay is not in the database connection as far as I can tell.

I'd really prefer to use the QtSql stuff instead of the awkward MySQL commands. Any ideas on how to add a bunch of rows to a MySQL database with QtSql instead of raw comands and with reasonable speed?

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 1):

Things to try:

- set your [EditStrategy](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qsqltablemodel.html#EditStrategy-enum) to `QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit`
- mass insert rows with [insertRows](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qsqltablemodel.html#insertRows)

and see if it helps...

Answer (score 1):

you should use begin before and commit after the loop, or turn off the autocommit feature from MySQL .. 
this will give you usually a performance increase of 50% or more ..